# ClosedXML gives argumentoutofrange exception during save as

Tags: closedxml

I am using ClosedXML latest version with templates. When i am calling workbook.saveas() function. closedxml is giving following error :-

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.GetPartById(String id)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.GenerateTables(XLWorksheet worksheet, WorksheetPart worksheetPart, SaveContext context, XLWSContentManager cm)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.GenerateWorksheetPartContent(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, XLWorksheet xlWorksheet, Boolean evaluateFormulae, SaveContext context)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument document, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(Stream stream, Boolean newStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(Stream stream, SaveOptions options)

Can anyone help me in this. ?

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
{

            using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook("C:\\report.xlsx"))
            {

                IXLWorksheet xl = workBook.Worksheet(1);
                xl.CopyTo(workBook, "Abc");

            IXLWorksheet w = workBook.Worksheet("Abc");
            IXLCell lastCell = w.Table("DayPart").LastCell();
            IXLCell firstCell = w.Table("DayPart").FirstCell();
            w.Tables.Remove("DayPart");
            w.Range(firstCell, lastCell).CreateTable("DayPart");
       
            workBook.Save();
            }

    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed XML giving ArguementOutOfRangeException on workbook.save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288998/closed-xml-giving-arguementoutofrangeexception-on-workbook-save)

Comment: Yes, we can close it

Comment: If you think so, you can delete it yourself.